# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away in PDO->__construct

Tags: php, mysql, fatal-error

I have this error that happens in an API only about once per 10k requests, it always happens on a specific type of API request (v2/download-file.php) although all the API points use the same database through the same database abstraction layer in PHP.
The stack trace of the error is this:

> [09-Jul-2023 14:56:50 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away in /usr/local/important/web/commons.shortpixel.com/dbsp.php:50
> Stack trace:
> #0 /usr/local/important/web/commons.shortpixel.com/dbsp.php(50): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=176....', 'db_user', Object(SensitiveParameterValue), Array)
> #1 /usr/local/important/web/commons.shortpixel.com/dbsp.php(85): ShortPixel\commons\Dbsp->connect()
> #3 /usr/local/important/web/commons.shortpixel.com/dbsp.php(155): ShortPixel\commons\Dbsp->__call(Array, Array)
> #4 /usr/local/important/web/commons.shortpixel.com/dao/pic-queue.php(278): ShortPixel\commons\Dbsp->query('UPDATE PicQueue...', Array)
> #5 /usr/local/important/web/api2.shortpixel.com/v2/class/file-serve-controller.php(129): ShortPixel\commons\dao\PicQueue->setDownloaded('f0469cb57bd0d0e...')
> #6 /usr/local/important/web/api2.shortpixel.com/v2/download-file.php(14): ShortPixel\api\FileServeController->run()

The error is triggered at a few milliseconds after the API point is called and it's on the first (and only) database connection of the respective API point, before running the actual query that is visible in the trace (UPDATE PicQueue SET Downloaded = '1' WHERE URLMD5 = ?). The API point only does some file_exists() checks before calling the setDownloaded() method that tries to connect and run the query.

Any advices on how to hunt this bug down would be much appreciated.

Comment: 1st check : What is `wait_timeout` mysql variable value in your system ?

Comment: wait_timeout=100

Comment: I will try although I'm not sure it would help since all the times the error happens, it happens within 2-6 milliseconds after the script is called...

Comment: I have tried the *_timeout=300 but no luck. The error still appears every now and then